# How to get a list of tokens, and the details of tokens, such as decimal, name

Tags: ripple, xrp

I would like to get the list of tokens, or is there any way to know if a transaction is a token creation transaction?

Comment: Please share your attempts and we will try to help you but don't expect someone to do all your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since anyone can issue a token in the XRPL at little effort, there are a lot of tokens that are not worth anything to most people. But if you want the full set of tokens in existence, you need to download [the full ledger data](https://xrpl.org/ledger_data.html) and read through it for [RippleState objects](https://xrpl.org/ripplestate.html) (trust lines) with a nonzero `Balance`. This is a lot of effort (a full ledger is several gigabytes last I heard, about half of which is RippleState objects).

As for the second half of your question, "token creation" in the XRPL is not always a singular event. More tokens can be created and destroyed "on demand" by Payment or OfferCreate transactions in various contexts. But as a general rule, in [transaction metadata](https://xrpl.org/look-up-transaction-results.html#2-interpret-metadata) if you see a `ModifiedNode` entry for a `RippleState` object whose `Balance` changed, that represents a change in token balances. Depending on which account is considered the "high" or "low" node, the `Balance` going up or down can represent adding or removing tokens from that line. The larger context also matters: sometimes you have an increase in tokens in one line that corresponds to a decrease in tokens on another line. (This is called [rippling](https://xrpl.org/rippling.html) and that's the only way tokens can be transferred from one holder to another.)